# Set-Content sporadically fails with "Stream was not readable"

Tags: powershell

I have some PowerShell scripts that prepare files before a build. One of the actions is to replace certain text in the files. I use the following simple function to achieve this:

```
function ReplaceInFile {
    Param(
        [string]$file,
        [string]$searchFor,
        [string]$replaceWith
    )

    Write-Host "- Replacing '$searchFor' with '$replaceWith' in $file"

    (Get-Content $file) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "$searchFor", "$replaceWith" } |
    Set-Content $file
}
```

This function will sporadically fail with the error:

```
Set-Content : Stream was not readable.
At D:\Workspace\powershell\ReplaceInFile.ps1:27 char:5
+     Set-Content $file
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (D:\Workspace\p...AssemblyInfo.cs:String) [Set-Content], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

When this happens, the result is an empty file, and an unhappy build. Any ideas why this is happening? What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Try storing the new content in a variable then putting in a short Start-Sleep before the Set-Content. A file lock that has not cleared is my first guess at the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I thought of that, but it's messy! I like the solution provided by Martin Brandl better.

Comment: How can this erroneous behaviour be reproduced? Any hints on line/file length? Complexity of the search pattern? OS, PS version? @AlanSmith5482

Comment: @danBhentschel, maybe something is locking your file like anti-virus/anti-malware scanner.

Comment: @AlanSmith5482 ```$tc = $(Get-Content test.txt | 
% {echo $($_ -replace "test1","test2")}); $tc > test.txt``` Does this work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sorry, I have no idea why this happens but you could give my `Replace-TextInFile`
 function a try. If I remember correctly I had a similar issue using `Get-contet` as well:

```
function Replace-TextInFile
{
    Param(
        [string]$FilePath,
        [string]$Pattern,
        [string]$Replacement
    )

    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText(
        $FilePath,
        ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($FilePath) -replace $Pattern, $Replacement)
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Preliminary testing indicates that this does seem to be more reliable, and it's an easy drop-in to my current code! As a side-note, this function, as-is, was mangling a © symbol in some of my files, and so I needed to pass `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default` to both the read and write.

Comment: Perfect, I had the same issue and this approach appears to work much better.  I added [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 to both read and write.

Comment: Just had the same issue and this solved the occasional error. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this and it turned out to be that the files I was trying to change were part of a solution that was open in Visual Studio.  Closing Visual Studio before running fixed the problem!

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by [joelsand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232444/joelsand) there's a slight improvement that can be made to [Martin Brandl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163423/martin-brandl)'s answer.

```
function Replace-TextInFile
{
    Param(
        [string]$FilePath,
        [string]$Pattern,
        [string]$Replacement, 
        [System.Text.Encoding] $Encoding
    )

    if($Encoding) {
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText(
            $FilePath,
            ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($FilePath, $Encoding) -replace $Pattern, $Replacement),
            $Encoding
        )
    } else { 
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText(
            $FilePath,
            ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($FilePath) -replace $Pattern, $Replacement)
        )
    }
}
```

Example:

```
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
Replace-TextInFile -FilePath $fullPath -Pattern $pattern -Replacement $replacement -Encoding $encoding
```

Comment: I was facing exact same issue on Win11, solved it using this function

Answer (score 3):

Using the `-Raw` switch on `Get-Content` will read the file in its entirity as a single string. Replacing all values in that would be much faster than having the code iterate line by line.

Try

```
(Get-Content $file -Raw) -replace $searchFor, $replaceWith | Set-Content $file
```

Comment: I like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your file was locked by another process?  You can use the findopenfile module from the gallery to see if there's a lock:  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/FindOpenFile

Or search the handles in sysinternals process explorer.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer